# MYSQL Calculate Column value based on a Case Statement and other Row Values

Tags: mysql, case

I am completely new to MYSQL so apologies for the question, but I am not sure where to start.

I have a mysql table that looks like the below;

Table_1

```
Record_ID   Price   Price_Difference    New_Value
1           100     null
2           101     1
3           115     14
4           135     20
5           95      -40
6           80      -15
```

What I want to do is add and entry for record 1 of null since there is no price difference.

For record 2 I want 'New_Value' to be the price difference value of 14 divided by a value dependent on the Price in the previous record 1.

e.g. 14/@var_1

Where

```
@var_1 = (case 
when price_1 < 50 then 0.5
when price_1 between 50.001 and 100 then 1
when price_1 between 100.001 and 150 then 1.25
when price_1 between 150.001 and 150 then  1.4
....etc.
end case
```

I presume this can be done in MYSQL and ideas how I can go about it?

Comment: Are your `Record_ID` always _guaranteed_ to be sequential with _no gaps_ in the order?

Comment: They should always be sequential, but there could in theory be gaps, although in this case there are not.

Comment: Then the second of my queries below ought to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by joining two aliases of the same table, whereby one points to the current `Record_ID` and the other points to the previous `Record_ID` by adding 1 to it in the join condition.

This can only work if the rows for `Record_ID` are guaranteed to be sequential with no intervening gaps.

```
SELECT
  pcur.Price,
  pcur.Price_Difference, 
  CASE 
    WHEN plast.Price < 50 THEN (pcur.Price_Difference / 0.05)
    WHEN plast.Price BETWEEN 50.001 AND 100 THEN (pcur.Price_Difference / 1)
    WHEN plast.Price BETWEEN 100.001 AND 150 THEN (pcur.Price_Difference / 1.25)
    WHEN plast.Price BETWEEN 150.001 AND 200 THEN (pcur.Price_Difference / 1.4)
    ELSE 999 # don't forget your else case
  END AS var_1
FROM
  /* First aliased table is the current record */
  prices pcur
  /* Second aliased table is the previous one, whose id is one behind */
  LEFT JOIN prices plast ON (pcur.Record_ID = plast.Record_ID + 1);
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/552ee/7

A slower method will work if the `Record_ID` have potential gaps in sequence, using a subselect to retrieve the `Price` from the previous row via `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.  This will have not-super performance on a large dataset.

```
SELECT 
  rid,
  Price,
  Price_Difference,
  CASE 
    WHEN var_1 < 50 THEN (Price_Difference / 0.05)
    WHEN var_1 BETWEEN 50.001 AND 100 THEN (Price_Difference / 1)
    WHEN var_1 BETWEEN 100.001 AND 150 THEN (Price_Difference / 1.25)
    WHEN var_1 BETWEEN 150.001 AND 200 THEN (Price_Difference / 1.4)
    ELSE 999 # don't forget your else case
  END AS var_1
FROM (
  SELECT
    Record_ID rid,
    Price, 
    Price_Difference,
   /* Subselect returns only one Price from the previous Record_ID which may not be in sequence */
   (SELECT Price FROM prices WHERE Record_ID < rid ORDER BY Record_ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS var_1
  FROM prices
) pcalc
```

And here's a demo of this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/552ee/5